# Initialize an array of integers in a loop

Tags: arrays, scala

I want to initialize an array of consecutive integers (say from 1 to 100) in Scala.

```
val N = 100
val arr = new Array[Int](N)
```

What is the best way of doing this in both imperative and functional paradigms?

Answer (score 4):

There is a dedicated `Array` builder ([`Array.range`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Array$.html#range(start:Int,end:Int):Array[Int])) for the purpose of building an `Array` as a range:

> def range(start: Int, end: Int): Array[Int]

```
Array.range(0, 10)
// Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Functional, concise & general

The most general functional way to initialize arrays would probably be `tabulate`:

```
Array.tabulate(100)(_ + 1)
```

Here, the first argument is the size of the array, and the second argument is the function that maps indices to values.

---

#### Imperative: cumbersome, but very fast

If you want to do it as fast as possible using a single thread, then the following imperative code would probably be difficult to beat, because it does not use any higher order functions anywhere:

```
val N = 100
val a = new Array[Int](N)
var i = 0
while (i < N) {
  a(i) = i + 1
  i += 1
}
```

It also has the advantage that you have the control over the array, so you don't have to allocate any new memory if you already have an allocated array.

---

#### With parallel collections

If the initialization would be less trivial (not just increment an integer), the following parallelized version might work faster for very large `N`:

```
val arr = new Array[Int](N)
for (i <- (0 until N).par) {
  arr(i) = i + 1
}
```

---

#### Quick & dirty (and probably just as fast as the imperative version anyway)

As already mentioned in the comment, in this simple case

```
(1 to 100).toArray
```

would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are from the world of ***imperative*** programming, you will find this technique familiar:

```
for (i <- 0 to N-1) {
  arr(i) = i + 1
}
```

Note that arrays in Scala are accessed using curved paranthesis and not square ones (like in Java, C etc).

A more ***functional*** way to initialize the array would be:

```
val arr = (1 to N).toArray
```